# Strange behaviour: Getting many upvotes/downvotes in a row

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

I experienced something strange on [my reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3336423/jpo38?tab=reputation) two times:

- 2016-05-24: Got three downvotes in a row (in 2 minutes) for three different and completely unrelated questions I asked years ago.
- 2016-05-13: Got four upvotes in a row (in 1 minute) for four different and completely unrelated answers I asked years ago.

Could this be a due to some bug or hack or anything like that? It's really surprising to see the same behavior repeated for old questions/answers with no activity.

Or could it simply be someone who checked my account and went to see the questions/answered I posted and played with the up/down vote button...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you most likely annoyed someone (which caused him/her to visit your profile page and downvote some of your answers) or made someone's day (and the reverse happened).

Voting based on the person who wrote the post is not allowed; one should vote on content. Therefore, there are algorithms in place which will revert these votes (both up and down) if it's done too often (this is called ['serial voting'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)), but three/four votes seems not enough to trigger it.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Not much point answering a dupe of a *FAQ*; just flag and move on.